# Proof of Idempotency for Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, idempotents

I'm currently looking at achieving some proof that an $n \times n$ matrix (let's say $Y$) is idempotent if and only if $I_n-Y$ is an idempotent matrix, (with $I_n$ being the identity matrix).

I have so far proved that $I_n-Y$ is idempotent if $Y$ is idempotent as:

$(I_n-Y)^2 = I_n - 2Y + Y = I_n - Y$ hence idempotent.

But I don't know if this helps me at all and how to flip it so that if $I_n - Y$ is idempotent then $Y$ must be also idempotent.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you use MathJax? I don't understand well your notation.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know how to use that. I'm saying (in words) that if I take Y to be an idempotent matrix of size nxn and (I) to be the identity matrix of also size n. Then I can prove that (I - Y) is idempotent because if I square this I get the return of the identity matrix minus 2 times the matrix Y, plus 1 times the matrix A which then equals the identity matrix I minus the matrix Y hence proving the statement. However how can I prove that the reverse is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $Y \in \cal{M}_{n \times n}\mathbb{(K)}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is some field (with characteristic zero).

$\implies.$ Suppose that $Y$ is idempotent. Then, we know that $Y^2=Y.$ Hence

$$\begin{align}(I_n - Y)^2 & = (I_n - Y)(I_n - Y)\\
& = I_n^2 - I_nY -YI_n + Y^2\\
& = I_n -Y - Y + Y\\
& = I_n - Y
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $Y - I_n$ is also idempotent.

$\Longleftarrow.$ Supposee that $I_n - Y$ is idempotent. Then, we know that $(I_n - Y)^2 = I_n - Y.$ Hence

$$\begin{align}
(I_n - Y)^2 = I_n - Y & \implies I_n^2 - I_nY -YI_n + Y^2 = I_n - Y\\
& \implies I_n -2Y + Y^2 = I_n - Y\\
& \implies Y^2 = Y
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $Y$ is also idempotent. $\square$

Comment: Wow that's soo informative thank you very much!

Comment: You are very welcome! Any doubt just ask :)

Answer (score 2):

$(I-Y)^2=I-Y$ $\Rightarrow$ $Y^2-2Y=-Y$ $\Rightarrow$ $Y^2=Y$ hence it is idempotent

Comment: Thank you! Is this from a particular theorem or is it just taken from rules for Idempotency?